# Improving running time in matlab code

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing

I wrote a matlab code for detecting circles in gray scale image using Hough Transform. I would like to minimize running time as much as possible.

The edge detection I use is custom implementation, but its running time is fast enough for what I need (about 0.06 seconds). However, the bottleneck is the rest of the code (total running time is about 6.35 seconds). BTW I used tic/toc to calculate running time.

Here is the code, I would really appreciate it if anyone could have a look:

```
function [ circles ] = findCircles(img)

 % set low and high bounds for radii values
    minR = 9; 
    [imgRows, imgCols] = size(img);
    maxR = ceil(min(imgRows, imgCols)/2);

    tic

    % run edge detection on image
    edgeImg = edgeDetect(img);    
    % get image size
    [rows, cols] = size(edgeImg); 
    % initialize accumulator
    houghAcc = zeros(rows, cols, maxR);
    % get all edge pixels from image
    edges = find(edgeImg);

    % find number of edge pixels
    edgeNum = size(edges);

    % scan each edge 
    for currEdge = 1 : edgeNum

        % get current edge x and y coordinations
        [edgeY edgeX] =  ind2sub([rows, cols], edges(currEdge));
        % scan each all possible radii
        for r = minR : maxR
            % go over all possible 2*pi*r circle centers
            for ang = 0 : 360
                t = (ang * pi) / 180;
                cX = round(edgeX - r*cos(t));
                cY = round(edgeY - r*sin(t));

                % check if center found is within image boundaries
                if ( cX < cols && cX > 0 && cY < rows && cY > 0 )
                    % found circle with (cX,cY) as center and r as radius
                    houghAcc(cY,cX,r)=houghAcc(cY,cX,r)+1; % increment matching counter

                end
            end
        end
    end

    % initialize circle list
    circles = []; 
    % intialize index for next found circle
    nextCircleIndx = 1;
    % get counter list dimensions
    [sizeX sizeY sizeR] = size(houghAcc);

    % get max counter value from hough counter matrix
    m = max(max(max(houghAcc))); 
    % calculate the minimal pixels that circle should have on perimeter
    t = m * 0.42; 

    % scan each found circle
    for cX = 1 : sizeX
        for cY = 1 : sizeY
            for r = 1 : sizeR

                % threshold values
                if houghAcc(cX, cY, r) > t
                    % circle is dominant enough, add it
                    circles(nextCircleIndx,:) = [cY , cX , r ,houghAcc(cX, cY, r)];
                    % increment index
                    nextCircleIndx = nextCircleIndx + 1;                    
                end

            end

        end
    end

     % sort counters in descending order (according to votes for each
    % circle)
    circles = flipud(sortrows(circles,4));

    % get circle list's size
    [rows cols] = size(circles);

    % scan circle list and check each pair of found circles 
    for i = 1 : rows-1
        % get first circle's details:
        % center
        cX1 = circles(i,1);
        cY1 = circles(i,2);
        % radius
        r1 = circles(i,3);
        %hough counter
        h1 = circles(i,4); 

        for j = i+1 : rows

            %get second circle's details:
            % center
            cX2 = circles(j,1);
            cY2 = circles(j,2);
            % radius
            r2 = circles(j,3);
            %hough counter
            h2 = circles(j,4); 


            % check if circle's actual difference is smaller than minimal
            % radius allowed
            if (cX1 - cX2)*(cX1 - cX2)+ (cY1 - cY2)*(cY1 - cY2) < (min(r1,r2))*(min(r1,r2))  && abs(r1 - r2) < minR
                % both circles are similar, sum their counters and merge
                % them to a circle with their avaraged values
                circles(i,:)=[(cX1+cX2)/2, (cY1+cY2)/2, (r1+r2)/2, h1+h2];
                % remove similar circle
                circles(j,:)=[0,0,0,0]; 
            end
        end

    end

    sortParam = 3; % 1: x-center, 2: y-center, 3: radius, 4: hough counter

    % sort the circles by the sort parameter, in descending order
    circles = flipud(sortrows(circles,sortParam));

    % get number of remained circles (= rows with non-zero values)
    len = length(find(circles~=0))/4;

    % remove duplicate similar circles from previus step
    circles(circles == 0) = [];

    % reshape circle list back to matrix form (previous step converted it
    % to a vector)
    circles = reshape(circles,len,4);

    % get max value according to sort parameter
    m = max(circles(:,sortParam));

    %get size of new circle list (with no duplicate circles)
    [newH newW] = size(circles);

    % thresholding: remove hough counters that are less than 30% from sort
    % parameter
    for  i= 1 : newH
        % check if current circle's sorting parameter's value is smaller
        % than threshold
        if  m - circles(i,sortParam) < m * 0.3 
    %         plot(circles(i,1),circles(i,2),'xr'); % DEBUG - show centers
        else
            % remove current circle
            circles(i,:)=[0,0,0,0];
        end
    end

    % find number of remaining circles after thresholding
    len = length(find(circles~=0))/4;
    % delete rows that match circles removed in thresholding
    circles(circles==0)=[];
    % reshape circle list back to matrix form
    circles=reshape(circles,len,4);

    % convert circle list's values to integers (hough counters are already
    % integers)
    circles = uint8(circles(:,1:3));
    toc
end
```

Where can this code be improved? thanks for any help!

Comment: for - for - for - if twice in the algo. i'll try to come back to this later if someone else doesnt help out

Comment: try running it with `profile` so you'll have a better understanding of where **exactly** your code spend most of its time

Comment: Ditto.  The profiler is always the first step for performance issues.  Is there a sample image that this code can be run on?  It's pretty cumbersome to try and debug code that cannot be run in a representative fashion.

Comment: The image this code should work on can be found in this link:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47588150/balls4.tiff

Comment: One minor optimisation would be to replace `for ang = 0 : 360` with `for ang = 0 : 359` since, in circular thinking `0°==360°`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first `for` block that populates `houghAcc` matrix, I propose the following replacement:

```
r = minR : maxR;    
t = ( 0 : 359 ) * pi / 180; % following HighPerformaceMark suggestion
rsin = bsxfun( @times, r', sin(t) ); %'
rcos = bsxfun( @times, r', cos(t) ); %'
[edgeY edgeX] = find( edgeImg );
cX = round( bsxfun( @minus, edgeX, permute( rcos, [3 1 2] ) ) );
cY = round( bsxfun( @minus, edgeY, permute( rsin, [3 1 2] ) ) );
R = permute( repmat( r', [ 1 size(cX,1) size(cX,3) ] ), [2 1 3] ); %' to index accHough
% select valid indices
sel = ( cX > 0 & cY > 0 & cY < rows & cX < cols );
houghAcc = accumarray( {cY(sel(:)), cX(sel(:)), R(sel(:))}, 1, [rows, cols, maxR] );
```

For the second `for` block that scans each found circle, I propose the following replacement:

```
ind = find( houghAcc > t );
% sort the scores
sc = houghAcc(ind);
[sc si] = sort(  sc , 'descend' );
% convert linear indices to x,y,r
[cX cY r] = ind2sub( size( houghAcc ), ind(si) );
circles = [ cX(:) cY(:) r(:) sc(:) ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the illustration Shai! At the time being, I need to compute the mean, std, and median in circular neighborhoods centered at a given pixel. I came to a solution that is slow :-( Was wondering, it you might have an idea how to optimize the code? All this is done in the context of the DoG scale representation. The size of the circular filter is given by the radius associated at a specific scale (scalespace_radii): pastebin.com/WkS5ShMf Any suggestion on how to improve the computation is welcomed!

Comment: @Tin you are more than welcome to ask your question as a proper post here at stackoverflow. Give chance to more people to think about it with you.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, I posted already my question :-) You can find it here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724404/matlab-optimizing-code-for-computing-statistics-in-multi-scale-circular-neighbo