# matlab: optimizing code for computing statistics in multi-scale circular neighborhoods

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, image-processing, vectorization

I've a stack of images (`imgstack`) over which I would like to compute some statistics (`e.g. mean, std, median`) in multi-scale circular neighborhoods. For each image on the stack (`currscale`), the size of the circular neighborhood to be applied is pre-stored in a vector `imgstack_radii(ss)`. The size of the circular neighboorhoods change across the images on the stack. Some example values for the radius of the circular filters are `1.4142,1.6818,2.0000,2.3784`.

The code below does the work, however, since the size of my stack is pretty big (`1200x1200x25`) the computational time is very expensive. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize/vectorize the code? Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
[rows, cols, scls] = size(imgstack);
imgstack_feats = cell(scls,1);
[XX, YY] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);
for rr=1:rows
    for cc=1:cols
        distance = sqrt( (YY-rr).^2 + (XX-cc).^2  );

        for ss=1:scls
            % imgstack_radii contains the radius associated to a given scale, i.e.: radii = scale * sqrt(2)
            mask_feat_radii = (distance <= imgstack_radii(ss));
            currscale       = imgstack(:,:,ss);
            responses       = currscale(mask_feat_radii);

            imgstack_feats{ss}(rr,cc,:) = [mean(responses), std(responses), median(responses)];
        end
    end
end
```

After the feedback of @Shai and @Jonas, the final code looks like below. Thanks guys!

```
function disk = diskfilter(radius)
    height  = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
    width   = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
    [XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:width,1:height);
    dist    = sqrt((XX-ceil(width/2)).^2+(YY-ceil(height/2)).^2);
    circfilter = strel(dist <= radius);
end

for ss=1:scls
    fprintf('\tProcessing scale: %d radii: %1.4f\n', ss, imgstack_radii(ss));
    disk      = diskfilter(imgstack_radii(ss));
    neigh     = getnhood( disk );

    imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,1) = imfilter( imgstack(:,:,ss), double(neigh)/sum(neigh(:)), 'symmetric' );

    tmp = imfilter( imgstack(:,:,ss).^2, double(neigh)/sum(neigh(:)), 'symmetric' );
    imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,2) = sqrt( tmp - imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,1) );

    imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,3) = ordfilt2( imgstack(:,:,ss), ceil( sum(neigh(:))/2 ), neigh );
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all operations using filters, which should be significantly faster.
For each `imagestack_radii`, first create a circular mask:

```
n = getnhood( strel('disk', imagestack_radii(s), 0 ) );
```

- mean: use `imfilter` with `double(n)/sum(n(:))` as filter

  ```
  imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,1) = imfilter( imgstack(:,:,ss), double(n)/sum(n(:)), 'symmetric' );
  ```
- std: once you have the mean, you can compute the second moment using

  ```
  tmp = imfilter( imgstack(:,:,ss).^2, double(n)/sum(n(:)), 'symmetric' );
  imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,2) = sqrt( tmp - imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,1) );
  ```
- median: use [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html)

  ```
  imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,3) = ordfilt2( imgstack(:,:,ss), ceil( sum(n(:))/2 ), n );
  ```

Comment: Shai thanks! I was thinking about using the `strel('disk', radius)` filter, the problem is that the `radius` should be integer. I could of course discretize the radius as: `round(radius)`. Typical values for my radius are: `1.4142,1.6818,2.0000,2.3784,...`. In order not to lose precision, I would like to avoid to discretize the computations. That is also why I was considering the euclidian distance for masking the circular regions of interest. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Tin: You don't need to use `strel` for the neighborhoods for filtering, you can still use your original circular masks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys! I updated my post and included the final solution. @Jonas, I added a `diskfilter` function that produce the circular mask. I think, this is the way you suggested, right? The code takes now aound 2min. to process one image, which is faster than the original one. However, I've 2 points more. First, just for the sake of self-learning, is it possible to `vectorize` the original code? Second, although 2min. is much better, is it still possible to somehow improve the code?

Comment: @Tin use `profile` to see what takes the longest time and concentrate on that part.

Comment: @Tin BTW if this solution works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking on the "V" icon beside it.

Comment: @Shai, thank you! The `ordfilt` consumes most of the processing time. It takes about `98.439s` of the 2mins. It calls to a mex-function `images\private\ordf (MEX-file)`. Any idea hoe to improve that? Besides that, do you think, it's possible somehow to vectorize the initial code?

Comment: @Tin: median filters are slow by nature. There will be noticeable speed-up if your data are uint8. If you have to use double, you have to be patient.

Comment: @Shai,concerning the second moment for the var, its equal to var= ((x1-mean)^2+(x2-mean)^2+...+(xn-mean)^2)/n and from the code you suggested, if I'm not wrong, you're computing something like: (x^2 - mean)? is that right?

Comment: @Tin I was aiming at the third line of [this formula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/8/0/58075832b1900758227a9e8dc31539f1.png)(taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance))

Comment: @Shai, shouldn't it be therefore `sqrt( tmp - (imgstack_feats{ss}(:,:,1)).^2 )`. Note the `.^2` to have the `square of mean`.

Comment: @Tin you might be correct. I haven't looked that hard into it.